# VARCHAR Column contains both decimal or Money

Tags: sql

I have a varchar column that can either be a money or decimal data type.  Sample values stored are 500 & .02 for each example.

How can I test to see if it's Money or a decimal and if it is a decimal add a leading 0 in front of it so the result will be 0.02?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add sample table data, so we can see the difference.

Comment: What is the point of having either money or decimal? Why not make all the values either money or decimal(10,2)?

Comment: If you have money then you should have a currency column. If it's empty then it's a number otherwise it's a money. BTW a better approach would not use varchar column. Also keeping money in integer in cents makes sense.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You've already got a bunch of product specific answers...

Comment: and if it's a dollar it would return $500

Comment: What is "I have a varchar column that can either be a money or decimal data type" actually supposed to mean? The data type is varchar. It is containing numbers only. (So using varchar is obviously a bad idea). 500 and .02 are *both* numbers that *could* represent money (e.g. 500 USD and 2 Cents). You could detect money only if there were some currency in the string, e.g. 'USD 500'. Only then "How can I test to see if it's Money or a decimal" would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could convert all of the data to be consistently displayed as the Money datatype.

```
DECLARE @BadDesign TABLE (
    BadDataTyping VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @BadDesign (BadDataTyping) VALUES ('500')
INSERT INTO @BadDesign (BadDataTyping) VALUES ('.02')

SELECT * FROM @BadDesign
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,BadDataTyping) FROM @BadDesign

UPDATE @BadDesign
SET BadDataTyping=CONVERT(MONEY,BadDataTyping)

SELECT * FROM @BadDesign
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful for you:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('500 & .02','&',''),' ','')::DECIMAL(15,2);  -- result: 500.02 (decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for? It takes all values with a leading "." and adds a "0". The search pattern in the 3rd row can be adjusted if you want to identify you're decimal values somehow differently.

```
SELECT 
  CASE TRUE 
    WHEN LEFT( col1, 1 ) =  "." THEN CONCAT('0', col1 ) 
    ELSE col1
  END AS col1_formatted
FROM tab1
```